# Filtering custom events in GA by source site

Tags: google-analytics

I am developing a site with custom google analytics events. During development and testing were registered multiple events from 3 sources:

1. From xampp localhost in my computer (http://localhost/sitename)
2. From development server (http://sitename.demo.activit.sk)
3. From production server (http://www.sitename.sk)

Event example:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Registration', 'Registration of client', 'GE', 1);
```

In GA I would like to display events only from production site. Is there an option to filter the events like this?

Comment: Just clarifying, did that event get sent on those sites, into the same GA property? If so, you could add `hostname` as a secondary dimension, and then filter by the prod site.

Comment: Yes it is the same GA property.

Comment: Yeah, then just add a "hostname" as a secondary dim and filter by the prod site. You could either do this in a custom report, or in-line filter, or segment... etc.

Comment: Thanks, i've found it. Good solution.

Comment: Yes, in the interface. If you go to your Top Events report, then right above the "Event Category" column, there's a pull-down labeled "Secondary dimension". By the way, I'm not giving an official answer (or screenshots) as this is a reporting question and should go to Webmasters forum instead of this one.